# Converting multiple CSV files to ARFF java

Tags: java

I've compiled a program that reads in all .csv files from a specified directory and converts them to .arff format. However instead of putting the .arff files into a directory it adds all the .arff files to one large file.

Ideally i want all .arff files into a folder in fileDestination.

```
`public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        File path = new File("/test//file//path//CSVfolder");
        File [] files = path.listFiles();

        String fileDestination = "C://test//file//path//ARFFfolder";

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){

                  CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();
                  loader.setSource(files[i]);
                  Instances data = loader.getDataSet();
                  data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes()-1);
                  String[] options= new String[2];
                  options[0] = "-R";
                  options[1] = "last"; 

                  //Save the file in ARFF format
                  ArffSaver saver = new ArffSaver();
                  saver.setInstances(data);
                  saver.setFile(new File(fileDestination));
                  saver.writeBatch();  
            }
        }`
```

I understand the error is coming from `saver.setFile(new File(fileDestination));`

However i can't seem to get the correct syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You did this, but `fileDestination` is constant and points to the directory ("ARFFfolder"):

```
saver.setFile(new File(fileDestination));
```

Use this instead:

```
saver.setFile(new File(fileDestination, files[i].getName() + ".arff"));
```